# Is log(n-f(n)) big theta of log(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The problem is that I need to know if `log(n-f(n))` is big theta of `log(n)`, where `f(n)` is a lower order function than `n`, e.g., `log(n)` or `sqrt(n)`.

I tried to use some log rules and plotting seems to confirm the bound, but I can't get it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As `f(n)` is a lower order function than `n`, `f(n) = o(n)`. Hence, `n-o(n) < 2n` and `n - o(n) = O(n)`. Also, `n - o(n) > n - 0.01 n <=> 0.01 n > o(n)` (`0.01` can be specified with the `o(n)`). Therfore, `n - o(n) = Omega(n)`, and `n-o(n) = Theta(n)`.

As `log` function is an increasing function we can say `log(n-o(n)) = Theta(log(n))`.